# Avoiding Ignorance

Tags: expressions, idioms

Is the phrase "avoid ignorance" idiomatic? In my mind something is wrong about the combination of the verb "avoid" and the noun "ignorance".

Comment: I share your reservations.  And both [Google nGrams](http://bit.ly/1GQajeE) and [the COCA Corpus](http://i.imgur.com/HuEq7U1.png) agree the construction is essentially unused. Maybe because ignorance is the *default*? As in, it simply *can't be avoided*, only addressed? In other words, we do not "avoid ignorance", we "**pursue knowledge**".

Comment: "Avoid Ignorance" is a Facebook page.  I guess they claim if you watch their news broadcasts you will do this.

Comment: I always thought "***avoid tigers***" was one of the most mellifluous phrases in the English language. *Much* better than "[*cellar door*](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/02/14/magazine/14FOB-onlanguage-t.html)"!

Comment: It certainly makes more sense than "avoid potatoes".  What do you feel is wrong?

Comment: I dunno; I have a friend who has a dietary intolerance to the entire nightshade family and really does have to avoid potatoes, tomatoes, and peppers... My problem with the cited phrase is that we all start ignorant, and no matter what we do we may remain ignorant of how much we're still ignorant of... "avoid willful or careless ignorance" strikes me as better advice.

Comment: *Avoid ignorance*. It could be thought of as a clever way to say "Seek knowledge", or "Pursue enlightenment". By itself, I think it could make a swell bumper sticker.

Comment: Do you have any context where you've seen this phrase? A link? That might give us an idea of how you've seen it.

Comment: There is a difference between the phrase being wrong and simply not being used.  Not every reasonable sequence of words has made it into a web page that Google has scanned.  (In fact, "reasonable sequence of words" only gets 7 hits on Google.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your unease with "avoid ignorance" is due to it having a semantic meaning of an apparently similar type as "avoid inability to think" or "avoid being human", in that "ability to think" and "being human" are not something changeable by conscious choice, and hence it makes no sense to talk about "avoiding" them.

Similarly, ignorance of a particular issue is just a factual matter and not something that can be chosen. However, "avoid ignorance" is still possible when used to indirectly imply "avoid willful or careless ignorance" as suggested by *keshlam*. So it would not be quite a direct fit in semantics, but possible.

Also, you didn't mention your context, so it is hard to say much more. In some contexts you may actually want to say "avoid coming across as ignorant", which means something different.